# Changing alignment for links using bootstrap scrollyspy

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am struggling to justify the scrollyspy links to the center of the navbar. Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

The alignments on this site are funky, but on VSC they are normal.

Here is my css:

```
.nav-pills {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

I tried going with the flex approach.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the width of the `ul` element `100%`. If it isn't it can't center from its own width

Comment: can also be a different width though

Comment: The only think is is that I need it to be responsive to different types of devices. Is there any way to do that but still changing the width?

Comment: Use @media query's to change the width depending on the size of the screen.